# What is the difference between `long_integer` and `integer` in ada language?

Tags: ada

```
with ada.text_io;

procedure numbers is 

   int1 : integer := 2147483647; --almost 4 bytes
   int2 : integer := -2147483647;

   lng1 : long_integer := 2147483647;
   lng2 : long_integer := -2147483647;

begin 

   ada.text_io.put_line(int1'image);
   ada.text_io.put_line(int2'image);

   ada.text_io.put_line(lng1'image);
   ada.text_io.put_line(lng2'image);

end numbers;
```

result :

```
 2147483647
-2147483647
 2147483647
-2147483647
```

I am new to this programming language and suddenly found this `long_integer` and `integer` datatypes in the ada language are the same in size and the type of data they can represent is there any key difference between these two datatypes ?

Comment: The difference is that `Integer` is required and exists for all compilers, while `Long_Integer` is optional and so should never be used in portable code.

Comment: See also [_§3.5.4 Integer Types_](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-5-4.html)

Answer (score 3):

The Integer and Long_Integer are both 32 bits in the current Gnat compiler.
The Long_Long_Integer is 64 bits.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is

begin
   Put_Line ("Integer'First : " & Integer'Image (Integer'First));
   Put_Line ("Integer'Last  :" & Integer'Image (Integer'Last));
   Put_Line ("Integer size :" & Integer'Image (Integer'Size));
   Put_Line
     ("Long_Integer'First : " & Long_Integer'Image (Long_Integer'First));
   Put_Line ("Long_Integer'Last  :" & Long_Integer'Image (Long_Integer'Last));
   Put_Line ("Long_Integer'Size :" & Integer'Image (Long_Integer'Size));
   Put_Line
     ("Long_Long_Integer'First : " &
      Long_Long_Integer'Image (Long_Long_Integer'First));
   Put_Line
     ("Long_Long_Integer'Last  :" &
      Long_Long_Integer'Image (Long_Long_Integer'Last));
   Put_Line
     ("Long_Long_Integer'Size :" & Integer'Image (Long_Long_Integer'Size));
end Main;
```

The output of this program is:

```text
Integer'First : -2147483648
Integer'Last  : 2147483647
Integer size : 32
Long_Integer'First : -2147483648
Long_Integer'Last  : 2147483647
Long_Integer'Size : 32
Long_Long_Integer'First : -9223372036854775808
Long_Long_Integer'Last  : 9223372036854775807
Long_Long_Integer'Size : 64
```

Answer (score 3):

The major difference is the standard Integer type has a different guaranteed minimum range

```
 (–2 ** 15)+1 .. +(2 ** 15)–1 see here for Integer
```

vs

```
 (–2 ** 31)+1 .. +(2 ** 31)–1 see here for Long_Integer
```

So while for your current implementation they are the same, they may not be on other implementations.  You could imagine a 16 bit platform where Integer is -65536 to 65535 and Long_Integer is what you are currently seeing still.